# Steps in proving a limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

When I am given a sequence and asked to prove it from definition, I get lost as to what steps I should be taking and what my aim is.

Many thanks for the help.

For example, prove $a_n = \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2}$ tends to $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by proof from definition?

Comment: @Matthew Do you mean the $\epsilon-\delta$-definition?

Comment: yes i did mean that sorry. i always get lost half way through what am i aiming to do

Answer (score 1):

From definition, to prove this goes to $0$ we must prove that, given any $\epsilon>0$, we must find a $N$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>N}$ we have $|a_n-0|=|a_n|<\epsilon$.

We can simply substitute the formula for $a_n$ to get: $$|a_n|=\left|\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|$$

With the triangle inequality, we find $$\left|\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|=\frac{|2+(-1)^n|}{|n^2|}\leq \frac{3}{n^2}$$ (also note that $|n^2|=n^2$). Choosing $N=\sqrt{\frac{3}{\epsilon}}$ yields $|a_n|\leq\frac{3}{n^2}<\epsilon$. And now we're done.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

A sequence $a_n$ is said to be [convergent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvergentSequence.html) $ \iff$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=L$$
exists and is finite ($< \infty$), so by definition of limit
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists N | \quad \forall n > N \qquad \left| L-\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \right| <\epsilon$$
Hence, in your specific case $a_n = \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2}$, so you want to find $N \quad \forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \forall n > N$
$$ \left|0-\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| = \left| \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| <\epsilon$$
Now note that $a_n = \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2} > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\Rightarrow \left|0-\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| = \left|\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and using the limit definition you can find that in a neighbourhood of $\infty \quad \frac{2+(-1)^n}{n^2} < \frac{2 + 1}{n^2} = \frac{3}{n^2}$ thus
$$\left|0-\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| = \left|\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n^2} = 0 < \epsilon$$
That's the guideline, however what matters the most is the last step
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n^2} = 0$$
but it's simple: let $N=\sqrt{\frac{3}{\epsilon}}$ then you have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3}{n^2} < \frac{3}{\sqrt{\frac{3}{\epsilon}} ^2} = \frac{3}{3}\cdot \epsilon = \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean to show that "given any $\epsilon> 0$ there exist positive integer N such that if n> N, then $\left|\frac{2+ (-1)^n}{n}\right|< \epsilon$".

To do that, first observe that, for any n, $2+ (-1)^n\le 3$  so we have $\left|\frac{2+ (-1)^n}{n}\right|\le \frac{3}{n}$.

Now what?

Answer (score 0):

The aim is to show that $a_n$ gets arbitrarily close to 0 once $n$ exceeds some number. Like if you want $a_n$ to get within 1/4 of 0 -- that is, $|a_n| < 1/4$ -- it's sufficient for $n$ to be at least 3, since the sequence $a_1, a_2, ...$ goes $1/1, 3/4, 1/9, 3/16, 1/25 ...$. Formally, you have to show you can get within an arbitrary distance of 0, so you use the symbol $\epsilon$ (by convention) to represent any positive number; here I would observe that there is always some $m$ big enough so that $3/{m^2} < \epsilon$, and $|a_n| < 3/{m^2}$ whenever $n > m$.